# error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql

i am using slim-framework v2 and php to get json outputs.With this code,i am getting the error which is described on the subject.
The mysql tables are bad formatted and can't be changed now so i made these functions in this way because i am not very experienced. 
What's the best way to solve this?Would be better if it could be done with sql command so i can remove these functions from the main loop?Are the functions inside the loop bad?
ps: Let me know if the subject looks wrong.

test() is the main loop for the customer ids

```
function test($server, $user, $pass, $db) {
  $result = array();
  $sql = "SELECT cid from tasks where total!=0";
  $db = newDB($server, $user, $pass, $db);
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  foreach ($stmt as $v) {
    $result[] = ['cid'=> $v['cid'], 'test'=> toGet($server, $user, $pass, $db, $v['cid']), 'test2'=> toGet2($server, $user, $pass, $db, $v['cid'])];
  }
  echo json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

and the other functions

```
function toGet($server, $user, $pass, $db, $id) {
  $sql = "SELECT sum(`poso`) as posoe from `economics` where `custid`=:id and flag=0";
  $db = newDB($server, $user, $pass, $db);
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  return $row[0];
}

function toGet2($server, $user, $pass, $db, $id) {
  $sql = "SELECT sum(`poso`) as posoe from `economics` where `custid`=:id and flag=1";
  $db = newDB($server, $user, $pass, $db);
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  return $row[0];
}
```

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:**
Turning on the debug $app->config('debug', true),finally got the error
Type: ErrorException
Code: 4096
Message: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string
File: /var/www/api/newdb.php
Line: 6

```
function newDB($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
    $dbhost= $host;
    $dbuser= $user;
    $dbpass= $pass;
    $dbname= $db;
    $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbConnection->query('set names utf8');
    return $dbConnection;
}
```

**UPDATE2: Slim conf**

```
include 'newdb.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->config('debug', true);
$app->response->setStatus(200);
$app->contentType('application/json; charset=utf-8');
$app->get('/test/:server/:user/:pass/:db', 'test');
$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
    $app->response->setStatus(200);
    echo "Welcome!";
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: Ummm... what line generates this error?

Comment: It's line 6,my question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved with a single MYSQL Query by a guy on Freenode.

```
- Reconnecting on db for each query was bad.
- toGet() toGet2() removed
```

I can fetch the data with single query

```
SELECT t1.custid as cid, sum(if(t2.flag=0,t2.poso,0)) as posoX,
sum(if(t2.flag=1,t2.poso,0)) as posoY from tasks t1 
left join economics t2 on t2.custid=t1.custid and t2.flag in (0,1) group by t1.custid;
```